# Excluding only one level of Log4j Logger

Tags: java, log4j, logging

I'm using Log4j in a application in which I also use Axis2 and Jetty web server.

I configured the Log4J property file to exclude these classes from logging when in debug priority. But when I did this, the other priority messages also began to be excluded from the main logger.

Is there a way that I can tell Log4j that I just want to log INFO logs from these classes while logging debug logs from my classes?

Here's what I have done:

```
#Jetty Server and Axis2
log4j.category.org.apache.axiom=DEBUG
log4j.additivity.org.apache.axiom=false
log4j.category.org.apache.axis2=DEBUG
log4j.additivity.org.apache.axis2=false

################# MAIN LOGGER #################
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, mainLogger

#File configuration
```

But as I said this configuration also exclude INFO messages from the main logger.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Try expanding on what it is you want, with examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, set the Root level to DEBUG, and

```
log4j.category.org.apache.axiom=INFO
log4j.category.org.apache.axis2=INFO
```

Also, do not set the additivity to `false`.

When you're starting from scratch, you might want to use the more modern XML config format right away. There, it would look like this:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender"> 
...
</appender> 

<category name="com.apache.axiom">
    <priority value="INFO" />
</category>

<root> 
    <priority value ="DEBUG" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" /> 
</root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem. I'll put in my to-do list the it's migration to XML format.

Answer (score 0):

Set the rootCategory to `INFO`, set an apropriate Logger of your classes (e.g. `org.myemployer.myapp`) to `DEBUG`

Comment: Bu then I would have two files? One with my classes and other with the other packages?

Answer (score -1):

Using this you can set your log level:

```
    import org.apache.log4j.Level;

    public static Logger logger = null;

    logger.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
```

and

```
 Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

Comment: Since I'm not using Log4J programatically this wouldn't solve my problem.